# Откуда взялись отступы во flex, если я их не задавал?

Tags: html, css

```css
.services {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%
}

.services-wrap {
  width: 1160px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.services-wrap ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <div class="services-wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="img/illustration-1.jpg" alt="Ноутбук">
        <h2>Веб-сайты</h2>
        <p>Мир никогда не будет прежним<br> после того как увидит ваш сайт!</p>
        <form action="#">
          <button value="Заказать" class="service-batton1">Заказать</button>
        </form>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/illustration-2.jpg" alt="Телефон">
        <h2>Приложения</h2>
        <p>Покорите топ-10 приложений в<br> AppStore и Google Play</p>
        <form action="#">
          <button value="Зауазать" class="service-batton2">Заказать</button>
        </form>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/illustration-3.jpg" alt="Диаграма">
        <h2>Презентации</h2>
        <p>Вы даже не подозреваете, <br>насколько вы изумительны!</p>
        <form action="#">
          <button value="Заказать" class="service-batton3">Заказать</button>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: Слева присутствует отступ, как его убрать?]

Comment: видимо дефолтные стили браузера работают и надо изначально применить reset.css (где сбрасываются все стили по умолчанию). Типа такого: https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вы их не задавали, а они есть :)

Всё дело в том, что Вы используете `ul` список, который по умолчанию имеет `padding`:

```
ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
```

Исправьте стили класса следующим образом:

```
.services-wrap ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Я понял, нужно было обнулить padding и margin именно для тег ul)
Спасибо за помощь=)

Comment: и reset.css применил=)